# Program in R, series of observation

Tags: r

I have a data set with a column where I have strings of repeated numbers ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4. 
Each string of 1, 2, 3... is one replication. I want to add a new column to my data set which will show that the first string of 1, 2,3, 4 is a replication 1, the other is 2 and so on.
I tried several loops but I am not good enough to go through it.
I will be glad for your help.
Best regards

Comment: This should be moved to stackoverflow, you will get a faster response there. I flagged it.

Comment: So does that mean that every time you get a '1' you start a new replication? Do the numbers ever increase by more than 1?

Comment: Yes, every time I get 1 is a new replication. Number increase always by 1

Comment: how to move it to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
rep <- cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) != 1) + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```